# OpenLayers.Layer.clone() not returning a unique Layer object

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm taking a layer (`layer_orig`) and calling the `clone` method to create a new layer (`layer_clone`) with same features, styles, etc. I am changing the name and `map` instance of the layer with:

```
layer_clone.map = null;
layer_clone.setName(name);
```

This works exactly as expected, even giving a unique layer id to the new layer.

However, if I then update the styleMap of `layer_clone`, the styleMap of `layer_orig` is updated as well - suggesting that `layer_clone` is a reference to `layer_orig` and not a completely unique Layer object.

Is there a way to get a unique Layer object that is a direct clone of another layer?

Comment: I have in mind to use cloning in the next few days, i ll let you know what i end up with.

Comment: That's be helpful! I look forward to hearing from you! Thanks!

Comment: have you tried cloning the stylemap also?

Comment: No, I hadn't. I just did clone the `OpenLayers.Style` object (`OpenLayers.StyleMap` doesn't have a `clone` method) - and it worked. @CaptDragon - add this as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @swatkins: roger that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried cloning the Style object seperately? :)

Comment: No, I hadn't. I just did clone the OpenLayers.Style object (OpenLayers.StyleMap doesn't have a clone method) - and it worked.

Comment: Could you please provide the syntax for how to clone an existing layers style? Thanks

Comment: it's `feature.style.clone();` I know you're getting undefined for this. Check what is undefined. Is it feature.style?